# 3 Foreign Keys to 1 table

Tags: mysql, sql, foreign-keys, innodb

i'd like to add 3 foreign keys to 1 table, but InnoDB gives an error. I can add the first foreign key on it's own, but then the same errors occurs with the other 2 keys. Here's the syntax:

```
CREATE TABLE Lokalen(
Gebouw VARCHAR(20) not null,
Verdieping INT not null,
Lokaal VARCHAR (3) not null,
Beweging BOOLEAN,
Computer BOOLEAN,
primary key (Gebouw, Verdieping, Lokaal));

CREATE TABLE Reserveringen(
Gebouw VARCHAR(20) not null,
Verdieping INT not null,
Lokaal VARCHAR (3) not null,
Begintijd TIME not null,
Eindtijd TIME,
Datum DATE not null,
Reserveringsnummer int not null,
primary key (Reserveringsnummer),
foreign key (Gebouw) REFERENCES Lokalen(Gebouw),
foreign key (Verdieping) REFERENCES Lokalen(Verdieping),
foreign key (Lokaal) REFERENCES Lokalen(Lokaal));
```

Hope you can help :)

Comment: please provide the actual error..

Comment: #1005 - Can't create table '***.Reserveringen' (errno: 150) (Details...)

Comment: what do the details say?

Comment: Let me guess : Table Reserveringen already exists ? Drop it first (if it's empty).

Comment: I got it now, just adding the ID's actually worked :p

Answer (score 1):

for composite FOREIGN KEY, the syntax is

```
FOREIGN KEY (Gebouw, Verdieping, Lokaal) 
    REFERENCES Lokalen(Gebouw, Verdieping, Lokaal)
```

I would strongly advise to use a simple surrogate key (like an autoincrement id), as PK in `Localen` and FK in `Reserveringen`).

To avoid errors :

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS Lokalen;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS Reserveringen;

CREATE TABLE Lokalen(
Gebouw VARCHAR(20) not null,
Verdieping INT not null,
Lokaal VARCHAR (3) not null,
Beweging BOOLEAN,
Computer BOOLEAN,
primary key (Gebouw, Verdieping, Lokaal));

CREATE TABLE Reserveringen(
Gebouw VARCHAR(20) not null,
Verdieping INT not null,
Lokaal VARCHAR (3) not null,
Begintijd TIME not null,
Eindtijd TIME,
Datum DATE not null,
Reserveringsnummer int not null,
primary key (Reserveringsnummer),
FOREIGN KEY (Gebouw, Verdieping, Lokaal) 
    REFERENCES Lokalen(Gebouw, Verdieping, Lokaal));
```

the way with surrogate keys

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS Lokalen;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS Reserveringen;

CREATE TABLE Lokalen(
Id Int Not null auto_increment PRIMARY KEY,
Gebouw VARCHAR(20) not null,
Verdieping INT not null,
Lokaal VARCHAR (3) not null,
Beweging BOOLEAN,
Computer BOOLEAN);

CREATE TABLE Reserveringen(
Id Int not null auto_increment PRIMARY KEY,
LokalenId Int not null,
Begintijd TIME not null,
Eindtijd TIME,
Datum DATE not null,
Reserveringsnummer int not null,

FOREIGN KEY (LokalenId) 
    REFERENCES Lokalen(Id));
```

Answer (score 0):

Apart from that you are duplicating all sorts of data (you should read up on normalizing database (or the "normaalvorm" :) )...

You need an index on the rows you want to use as foreign key. see http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-foreign-key-constraints.html

> InnoDB permits a foreign key to reference any index column or group of
>   columns. However, in the referenced table, there must be an index
>   where the referenced columns are listed as the first columns in the
>   same order.

Comment: Wel, it would be if the foreign key uses it. In the initial code there as one composite key, but seperate foreign keys. So for the actual foreign key you would be making (lets say, 'lokaal'), you would not have an index. So yes, PK is enough if it is actually used in the foreign key.

Answer (score 0):

You may add this outside create table :

```
Create Table Reserveringen(
.....
.....
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;
```